# Spam Filter - Python newbie

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, naivebayes

So I have the task of creating a classification algorithm in Python for an email dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase

I need to be able to process the dataset, apply my classification algorithm ( I have chosen 3 naive bayes versions ), print the accuracy score to the terminal and perform a 5 or 10 fold cross validation and find out how many emails are spam.

As you can see I have done some of the tasks but missing the cross validation and finding out how many emails are spam.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

import sklearn   
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Read data
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv').values

# What shuffle does? How it helps?
np.random.shuffle(dataset)


X = dataset[ : , :48 ]
Y = dataset[ : , -1 ]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = .33, random_state = 17)

# Bernoulli Naive Bayes
BernNB = BernoulliNB(binarize = True)
BernNB.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_expect = Y_test
y_pred = BernNB.predict(X_test)   
print ("Bernoulli Accuracy Score: ")
print (accuracy_score(y_expect, y_pred))

# Multinomial Naive Bayes
MultiNB = MultinomialNB()
MultiNB.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = MultiNB.predict(X_test)
print ("Multinomial Accuracy Score: ")
print (accuracy_score(y_expect, y_pred))

# Gaussian Naive Bayes
GausNB = GaussianNB()
GausNB.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_pred = GausNB.predict(X_test)
print ("Gaussian Accuracy Score: ")
print (accuracy_score(y_expect, y_pred))

# Bernoulli ALTERED Naive Bayes
BernNB = BernoulliNB(binarize = 0.1)
BernNB.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_expect = Y_test
y_pred = BernNB.predict(X_test)   
print ("Bernoulli 'Altered' Accuracy Score: ")
print (accuracy_score(y_expect, y_pred))
```

I have looked into cross validation and think I can apply this now, but its finding out how many emails are spam that I dont understand??? I have the different navie bayes versions accuracy, but how would I actually find the number of spam? The last column is either 1 or 0 and that defines if its spam or not? So I dont know how to go about it

Comment: I'm confused about exactly what you're asking. The count of y_true where spam==1 is the number of actual spam messages, the count of y_predicted where spam==1 is the number of predicted spam messages

Comment: Where does is say y_true == 1? I'm new to python and classification algorithsms so getting my head around it. At the moment all I understand the program to be doing is getting an accuracy score for each naive bayes type.

Comment: What I am trying to get at is how do I work out the number of spam emails?

Comment: In your case, your true y labels appear to be stored as `y_expect`, and your predicted y values are `y_pred`. My confusion is: Are you trying to tell how many _actual_ spam emails there are in your testing set? `y_expect.sum()`. How many emails you are predicting as spam based on your testing features? `y_pred.sum()`. How many you are misclassifying? That would be @mujjiga's answer below.

Comment: I was more confused what the accuracy score actually was. From the below answer I gather it as being the accuracy of emails correctly classified. But surely I can't be expected to find out how many actual spam emails there are in the whole dataset? Assuming everything in the dataset is correct

Comment: I understand no. I would say that, to me, "find the number of spam emails" in your instructions is extremely unclear on the part of whomever gave you those instructions, and I would ask for clarification. If you're just looking for the total number of actual spam emails in the dataset, then it would just be `Y.sum()` for a binary classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your class label 1 means spam, accuracy value you are calculating using `accuracy_score` will give you the number of spam emails that are correctly identified as spam. For example, 90% test accuracy implies 90 out of 100 test spam emails are correctly classified as spam.

Use `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_expect, y_pred)` for individual class level breakdown.

[sklearn Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

For example:

If `y_expect = [1,1,0,0,1]`
It mean you have 3 spam email and 2 non spam emails in your test data, and if `y_pred = [1,1,1,0,1]` then it mean your model have detected 3 of the spam emails correctly but also detected 1 non spam email as spam.

Comment: Right I'm with you, I get it now. So realistically when in my brief it says 'find the number of spam emails' I can't really know exacty?

Comment: `'find the number of spam emails` (in test data) normally implies find how well your model is able to detect spam email correctly. It a measure of how well your model is so that you can see which model is performing good at detecting spams emails (again on test data). But we assume if it does good on test data then it will do good on unseen data.